# Google MAP API does not work in https mode

Tags: google-maps

I have integrated Google MAP api into our application using Javascript but unfortunately it does not work in https mode until I click "Show all content" button displays in the bottom of IE. There is no problem with http mode. Please let me know how can I fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

are you including the Google MAP script in a protocol agnostic way or just using an http link? if you want to server both, the script pointing to google maps should be

```
<script src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
```

so that either http or https is used.

Comment: yes, I am using http link. Please see code
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;sensor=false&amp;key=ABQIAAAAx7fYbzWS9JASatHMdsyOlhRSU-98lp4o-N0srnpID3RXcvIUqxR7t-fylYx5xjYFygq3MpEkNAmclw" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: if you use an http link, and the page is loaded with HTTPS, all browsers will refuse to load it, since it's non-secure content in a secure page. Depending on user settings, they might ask the user to load "unsecure" or "other" content. If you format your script src as the example I've given ( is start with `//maps...` ) then the protocol is inherited ( it automatically switches between http and https )

Answer (score 0):

If you check the 'Enable Protected Mode' box under Internet Options > Security > Local Intranet this seems to have the effect of allowing the map to display in IE 8 and 9 for users on a corporate network.

This of course seems counter-intuitive, especially given the explanation in this [link](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/What-does-Internet-Explorer-protected-mode-do)
but it has solved the problem for my users on many occasions. Not ideal, but worth a shot if you can recreate the problem and see if this is the fix.